# ReactJs Modal in Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've loosely followed this [react modal](https://nainacodes.com/blog/create-an-accessible-and-reusable-react-modal) tutorial.
When I put the Modal inside a loop with multiple links and open the modal, It's opening all the modals (of course). I'm trying to work out how to open the appropriate modal (for the id)

**The Alert component with Modal in loop**

```
export default function Alert({}: Props) {
  const { alerts, loading } = useGetAlerts();
  const { isShown, toggle } = useModal();

  return (
    <div className={styles.alertHeader}>
      <div className={styles.title}>Alerts</div>
      <div className={styles.alertFrame}>
        <div className={styles.counter}>{`${alerts?.items.length}`}</div>
        <div className={styles.titleFrame}>
          <div className={styles.summaryTitle}>
            Outstanding <br></br>Alerts
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <SnakeLoader />
      ) : (
        alerts?.items.slice(0, 5).map((a) => (
          <div key={`id_${a}`} className={styles.alertFrame}>
            <div className={styles.titleFrame} id="titleFrame">
              <div className={styles.alertTitle} id="alertTitle">
                {' '}
                {`${a.message}`}{' '}
              </div>
              <div className={styles.alertLink} id="alertLink">
                <button onClick={toggle}>Click for More</button>
                <Modal
                  isShown={isShown}
                  hide={toggle}
                  modalContent={a.message}
                  headerText={a.id}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.alertClose} id="alertClose">
              X
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The Modal component**

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styles from './Modal.module.scss';
//https://nainacodes.com/blog/create-an-accessible-and-reusable-react-modal

export interface ModalProps {
  isShown: boolean;
  hide: () => void;
  modalContent: string;
  headerText: string;
}

export const Modal: FunctionComponent<ModalProps> = ({
  isShown,
  hide,
  modalContent,
  headerText,
}) => {
  const modal = (
    <div className={styles.modalContainer}>
      <div className={styles.styledModal}>
        <div className={styles.header}>
          <div className={styles.headerText}>{headerText}</div>
          <button className={styles.closeButton} onClick={hide}>
            X
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.content}>{modalContent}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return isShown ? ReactDOM.createPortal(modal, document.body) : null;
};
```

**The useModal method**

```
export const useModal = () => {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsShown(!isShown);
  const id = '';
  return {
    isShown,
    toggle,
    id
  };
};
```

Very new to React, any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is no need to render that much Modal components, render only one of it.

Add 1 extra state variable that will hold the `activeAlertItem` for modal. This variable will be set by `Click for More` button click for specified `alert`.

Once set - you are free to use either conditional rendering ie

```js
{activeAlertItem && (
  <Modal
    isShown={true}
    hide={() => setActiveAlertItem(undefined)}
    modalContent={activeAlertItem.message}
    headerText={activeAlertItem.id}
  />
)}
```

either whatever else you prefer.

Here is an example (with manual dummy data, sorry):

```js
interface IAlertItem {
  id: string;
  message: string;
}

const alertsItems: IAlertItem[] = [
  { id: "1", message: "test 1" },
  { id: "2", message: "test 2" },
  { id: "3", message: "test 3" }
];
const alerts = {
  items: alertsItems
};

export default () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [activeAlertItem, setActiveAlertItem] = useState<IAlertItem | undefined>(undefined);

  return (
    <div className={styles.alertHeader}>
      <div className={styles.title}>Alerts</div>
      <div className={styles.alertFrame}>
        <div className={styles.counter}>{`${alerts?.items.length}`}</div>
        <div className={styles.titleFrame}>
          <div className={styles.summaryTitle}>
            Outstanding <br></br>Alerts
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <SnakeLoader />
      ) : (
        alerts?.items.slice(0, 5).map((a) => (
          <div key={`id_${a}`} className={styles.alertFrame}>
            <div className={styles.titleFrame} id="titleFrame">
              <div className={styles.alertTitle} id="alertTitle">
                {" "}
                {`${a.message}`}{" "}
              </div>
              <div className={styles.alertLink} id="alertLink">
                <button onClick={() => setActiveAlertItem(a)}>
                  Click for More
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.alertClose} id="alertClose">
              X
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}

      {activeAlertItem && (
        <Modal
          isShown={true}
          hide={() => setActiveAlertItem(undefined)}
          modalContent={activeAlertItem.message}
          headerText={activeAlertItem.id}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit thirsty-tereshkova-g6zrk9]

Answer (score 2):

Currently each of your modals use the same piece of state to toggle its visibility, `isShown`. And `toggle` is the function that changes that state. In order to control the modals individually, we need a separate piece of state and a separate function to toggle that state for each individual modal you have created. One option could be getting rid of the `useModal` hook, and moving both `isShown` and `toggle` into the `Modal` component itself. This way when each `Modal` component is created, it has its own state instead of sharing it from that hook.

Comment: This a good approach, but it has a major drawback: Multiple modals could theoretically be shown at a time since their states are disconnected. Instead, I'd recommend that each modal should have a unique id (`uuid`). Then, on a child action (button click) it sets a parent-level state (`selectedModalId`) with its respective modal id. Now, when comparing this selected modal id state with each modal id, only 1 modal will be shown at a time.